# How to open a Shiny app from within an RStudio Gadget

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am working on a package that bundles a set of apps, and I want to have an [RStudio addin](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) that allows you to select the apps based on a categorization. This app is a [shiny gadget](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/gadget-ui.html), which is a special mini-version of a shiny app.

The problem is that :

- I can't use `runApp` from within another app, that's giving errors.
- I can't return the app that I want to launch, because I tried and it didn't do anything.

Inside a gadget server function I have following code:

```
observeEvent(input$done,{
      theapp <- shinyAppDir("Dir/to/app")
      stopApp(theapp)
    })
```

But to no avail. I can catch the app as a return value, but somehow it doesn't open automatically.

Comment: Question answered in QA style as I've been fighting this for half a day and I want to keep it somewhere as a reference. There is no better place but SO to have such a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get around this problem by using the `rstudioapi` package to send a command to the R console when closing the app. The code in the server function then becomes:

```
observeEvent(input$done,{
      command <- "shinyAppDir('Dir/to/app')"
      rstudioapi::sendToConsole(command)
      stopApp()
    })
```

A toy example to illustrate:

```
library(shiny)
ui2 <- fluidPage(
  title = "The Second App",
  plotOutput("plot")
)
server2 <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlot(hist(iris$Sepal.Length))
}

library(miniUI)
library(rstudioapi)
theGadget <- function(){
  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("Get some app"),
    miniContentPanel(
      renderText("Click on Done")
    )
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$done,{
      command <- "shinyApp(ui2, server2)"
      rstudioapi::sendToConsole(command)
      stopApp()
    })
  }
  viewer <- dialogViewer("Example")
  runGadget(ui, server, viewer = viewer)
}

theGadget()
```